# findAll-beautifulsoup-python can not work properly

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

When I used `findAll` function and I've faced a problem. `findAll` function can not work properly and it couldn't distinguish the end of `<td>` tag or cannot find `</td>`. It puts all the html code into `t1` variable that I've defined.
Any one can help? I put the output of it here.

```
t1 = soup.findAll('td',{'data': 'Text:'})
print('( Text:   ',t1.text,' )')
```

Output:

```
( Text:    helloworld  * , hello:  * . hiii * ;hello * ; </td>
      <td id="dtt" datetime="2018-12-06T19:08:56Z" data="Summary:">world hello</td>
      </tr>
```

if it works properly it should give us this output.

```
( Text:    helloworld  * , hello:  * . hiii * ;hello * ;  )
```

Also I should noticed that this works properly for any other `<td>` but just for this `<td>` I have problem. I think there is some wrong about `*`, `;` or the space at the end. what is your opinion?

Comment: Could you share the relevant part of the raw HTML you are parsing? Also, have you tried switching to `html5lib` or `lxml` parsers? https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#installing-a-parser.

Comment: Thankyou alecxe, switching to lxml works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may obtain cleaner parse results from dirty input using this:

```
    soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml-xml')
```